# Big problem automating Microsoft Forms, can anyone provide some insight?

Tags: javascript, automation

TL;DR; Used `document.getElementsByClassName('office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius')[0].value = 0` in console to fill up Microsoft Forms blanks but when submitting form still thinks the blanks are empty. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :D

Alright hi guys, so I just spend the last 2 days trying to figure out how I can extract data from excel and then use that data to automatically fill up a Microsoft form.
I thought I finally figured it out and everything worked perfectly but then I faced a huge roadblock! I'm hoping someone can help me can I don't know very much at all about JavaScript since I just started 2 days ago.

Here's my problem, i managed to fill up the blanks in the Microsoft Form by pasting this code in the console of my browser.

`document.getElementsByClassName('office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius')[0].value = 0`

However, when i go to submit the form it reacts as though there has been no input in that blank.
I really don't know how to fix this and as of now the code is s perfect except for this one hiccup.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF2Cf.jpg) is what the form looks like.
Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance, happy coding :D

Comment: are all the values supposed to  be set to 0?

Comment: Nope only this specific one. The code pulls information from excel and converts it to javascript so that it can be pasted in the console